# creating a javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

in asp-mvc, i have a partial view which contains this:

```
<table id="grid">
</table>
<div id="pager1">
</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$('#grid').jqGrid({
    url: '/Employee/JsonEmployee',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames: ['NUMBER', 'NAME', 'ROLE', 'OPERATIONS'],
    colModel: [
{ name: 'NUMBER', index: 'number', width: 200, sortable: false, align: 'center' },
{ name: 'NAME', index: 'name', width: 300, sortable: false, align: 'center' },
{ name: 'ROLE', index: 'role', width: 200, sortable: false, search: false, align: 'center' },
{ name: 'OPERATIONS', index: 'operation', width: 200, sortable: false, search: false, align: 'center'}],
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    pager: '#pager1',
    sortname: 'number',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    height: "100%",
    caption: "EMPLOYEES"
});
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager1', { del: false, add: false, edit: false }, {}, {}, {}, { width: 600 });

</script>
```

it is working fine but then, i decided to remove the script at the bottom of my view and put it in a javascript(.js) file in the Scripts folder: Local.js

```
function () {
$('#grid').jqGrid({
    url: '/Employee/JsonEmployee',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames: ['NUMBER', 'NAME', 'ROLE', 'OPERATIONS'],
    colModel: [
{ name: 'NUMBER', index: 'number', width: 200, sortable: false, align: 'center' },
{ name: 'NAME', index: 'name', width: 300, sortable: false, align: 'center' },
{ name: 'ROLE', index: 'role', width: 200, sortable: false, search: false, align: 'center' },
{ name: 'OPERATIONS', index: 'operation', width: 200, sortable: false, search: false, align: 'center'}],
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    pager: '#pager1',
    sortname: 'number',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    height: "100%",
    caption: "EMPLOYEES"
});
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager1', { del: false, add: false, edit: false }, {}, {}, {}, { width: 600 });

  };
```

i called the script file in my _Layout.cshtml:

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Content/css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Content/themes/base/css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Scripts/js")"></script>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Local.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>
```

when i run my web app, it's not working good anymore... the jqGrid is not displayed anymore... where could be the problem?

Comment: Try moving it higher in the page. It could be that you're including that file too late into the HTML.

Comment: How are you going to call that anonymous function?

Comment: already tried that but it didnt work... is my creation of a javascript file correct?

Comment: i really dont know if my javascript file is correctly done... what should be the correct format? i believe that the js looks for the id that matches it...

Comment: if you want to know that your javascript is correctly or not you can use Inspect Element (Firebug) to console what is your mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code in Local.js is never executed, you can call it when the dom is ready with `$(document).ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#grid').jqGrid({
        url: '/Employee/JsonEmployee',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['NUMBER', 'NAME', 'ROLE', 'OPERATIONS'],
        colModel: [
    { name: 'NUMBER', index: 'number', width: 200, sortable: false, align: 'center' },
    { name: 'NAME', index: 'name', width: 300, sortable: false, align: 'center' },
    { name: 'ROLE', index: 'role', width: 200, sortable: false, search: false, align: 'center' },
    { name: 'OPERATIONS', index: 'operation', width: 200, sortable: false, search: false, align: 'center'}],
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        pager: '#pager1',
        sortname: 'number',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        height: "100%",
        caption: "EMPLOYEES"
    });
    jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager1', { del: false, add: false, edit: false }, {}, {}, {}, { width: 600 });
});
```

Comment: still not working, is the way i call my javascript file correct?

Answer (score 0):

The function in your Local.js file has no name... you didn't call the function, so everything inside your Local.js doesn't work! You can use:

```
window.onload = function() {
  //your code here
}
```

but it's not recommended to use. You should give name to your functions and call them

Comment: if i remove the function, why it is not working? it's supposed to see that it matches the id of #grid and start executing the script, right?

Comment: To separate javascript into another file, you have to create functions and call them. You cannot write code directly like what you did in your <script> tag. You can have another way to do that if you want, but it's not good. Let me edit my answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

okay, i did what Musa said but instead of calling it in the _Layout.cshtml, i called it in my view... my view is a partial view so i gues it is affected by that(?)